How to Crop Image Within a Specific Rectangle Overlay in Android Jetpack Compose?
I have a requirement to capture an image within a rectangle overlay displayed on the screen and crop it precisely to the rectangle's bounds. However, the cropped image is either stretched or includes parts outside the rectangle boundary.
Here is my capturePhoto function:
    override suspend fun onCapturePhoto(
    controller: LifecycleCameraController, onResult: (Result<Bitmap>) -> Unit
) {
    controller.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(application),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
            override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                super.onCaptureSuccess(image)

                try {
                    val rotationDegrees = image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
                    val bitmap = imageProxyToBitmap(image)

                    // Rotate the bitmap if necessary
                    val correctedBitmap = rotateBitmap(
                        bitmap, rotationDegrees
                    )

                    // Calculate cropping rectangle dimensions
                    val width = correctedBitmap.width
                    val height = correctedBitmap.height
                    val centerX = width / 2
                    val centerY = height / 2

                    // 20% up and 20% below the center
                    val cropHeight =
                        (height * 0.4).toInt() // Total height (20% above + 20% below)
                    val cropTop =
                        (centerY - cropHeight / 2).coerceAtLeast(0) // Ensure it's not negative
                    val cropBottom =
                        (cropTop + cropHeight).coerceAtMost(height) // Ensure it doesn't exceed the image

                    // Create the cropped bitmap
                    val imageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        correctedBitmap, 0,         // Start from the left (full width)
                        cropTop,   // Start from the calculated top
                        width,     // Full width
                        cropBottom - cropTop // Height of the cropped area
                    )

                    onResult(Result.success(imageBitmap))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    onResult(Result.failure(e))
                } finally {
                    image.close() // Ensure resources are released
                }
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                super.onError(exception)
                onResult(Result.failure(exception))
            }
        })
}
    
// Helper: Convert ImageProxy to Bitmap
private fun imageProxyToBitmap(imageProxy: ImageProxy): Bitmap {
    val buffer = imageProxy.planes[0].buffer
    val bytes = ByteArray(buffer.capacity())
    buffer.get(bytes)
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
}


private fun rotateBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, rotationDegrees: Int): Bitmap {
    val matrix = Matrix().apply {
        postRotate(rotationDegrees.toFloat())
    }
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, matrix, true)
}

Here is the rectangle overlay code in my Compose screen:
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
    .drawWithContent {
        val canvasWidth = size.width
        val canvasHeight = size.height
        val width = canvasWidth * .97f
        val height = width * 3 / 4.5f

        drawContent()
        drawRect(Color(0x99000000)) // Semi-transparent overlay

        val newHeight = canvasHeight * 0.35f
        val newTopOffset = (canvasHeight - newHeight) / 2

        // Transparent rectangle
        drawRoundRect(
            topLeft = Offset(
                (canvasWidth - width) / 2,
                newTopOffset
            ),
            size = Size(width, height),
            color = Color.Transparent,
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(24.dp.toPx()),
            blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
        )

        // White border
        drawRoundRect(
            topLeft = Offset(
                (canvasWidth - width) / 2,
                newTopOffset
            ),
            color = Color.White,
            size = Size(width, height),
            cornerRadius = CornerRadius(24.dp.toPx()),
            style = Stroke(width = 2.dp.toPx()),
            blendMode = BlendMode.Src
        )
    }
    .background(Color.Black)) {
    AndroidView(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), factory = {
        PreviewView(it).apply {
            this.controller = controller
            controller.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner)
        }
    })
}

Issues:

How do I accurately crop the image to match the bounds of the
rectangle overlay?
The current approach either stretches or includes parts outside the
rectangle.

Any suggestions or code improvements to ensure the cropped image precisely matches the rectangle's dimensions would be highly appreciated.
ScreenShot -> CameraPreview with overlay on Real device

Photo -> After cropped image


The issue here is, that the CameraPreview isn't really able to fillMaxSize(), since it's dimension is either 4:3 or 16:9. Looking at your Image it seems to match the height and draws wider than your screen. Not sure how to fix that tho, sorry

@m.reiter
Thank you! I set the aspect ratio to 16:9, and it works fine. However, I have a question regarding the image cropping. I cropped the image by centering it and cropping 20%up from center and 20% below from center. Is this a good approach for cropping within a rectangular area, or is there a better method?
Update: When I set the aspect ratio, the camera preview adjusts to that ratio, but I would like the camera to display in full-screen mode instead.
